# Return Array in JSON as Array or String for Two Dimensional Array

Tags: php, objective-c, json

Using an API (which I am writing) I need to return a fairly simple array from a server running PHP using JSON for use in Objective-C.

On the phone, the code will be added to an array of the following form:

```
NSArray *carPics =@[@[@"ford",@"ford.png"],@[@"bmw",@"bmw.png"];
```

I can return the above in JSON as a string by escaping all the special characters--a bit tedious but possible, or replacing the special characters with magic strings like ***. and then make the string as an array using :

```
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"***"];
```

On the other hand, I could create an array in PHP and return the array to the phone which would then have to convert the array to Objective-C.

```
$carpics = array(
  array(
    "ford" => "ford.png",
    "bmw" => "bmw.png",
  );
```

The downside of this is it would involve more conversions.

Is either approach better or are they six of one, half a dozen of the other?

**Edit**

Currently the JSON sent by server looks like this:

```
{"carpics":{"ford":"ford.png","bmw":"bmw.png"}}
```

I am trying to decode it on phone using:

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonFeed
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];


        NSMutableArray *carPics = [[json objectForKey:@"carpics"]mutableCopy];
NSArray *myArray = carPics;
```

This works fine. I have verified that json is a dictionary. Unfortunately, I have also verified using kindOfClass that carpics or myArray is not an array as I want but a dictionary too.

If I try to grab the first element of myArray using:

```
 NSArray *object = myArray[i];
```

I get an error:

```
[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174449420'
```

I really want an array as I wish to go through each element of the array in order one at a time.

What do I need to do for my JSON to be a proper array of arrays.  I can either change the JSON coming from the server or process the JSON differently on the phone.

Here is the PHP code that creates the JSON:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$ret = array("ford"=>"ford.png","bmw"=>"bmw.png");
echo json_encode(array('carpics'=>$ret));
```

Comment: What about using [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization/1415493-jsonobjectwithdata?language=objc)

Comment: There is already tool for this as MER mentioned, from PHP you send the JSON, then in ObjC, you just need to use NSJSONSerialization to auto decode those json strings into NSArray/NSDictionary automatically.

Comment: HI MER, I am trying NSJSONSerialization but am not getting an array out of it with the current code. Can you look at what might be wrong above?